# How to translate date in int format in XML

Tags: php, xml, ado

I am trying to parse an XML data to an array but the problem is the date is a int type like below.

```
<xml xmlns:s='uuid:RTYUI1-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
xmlns:dt='uuid:DFR12345-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
<s:Schema id='RowsetSchema'>
<s:ElementType name='row' content='eltOnly'>
    <s:AttributeType name='AdmissionDate' rs:number='1' rs:nullable='true' rs:maydefer='true' rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='int' dt:maxLength='4' rs:precision='10' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
    </s:AttributeType>
 <s:extends type='rs:rowbase'/>
</s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
 <z:row AdmissionDate='42569'/>
 </rs:data>
```

I am using xmlPasser.class.php class from here and i t outputs like below:

```
  [rs:data] => Array
            (
                [z:row] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [0_attr] => Array
                            (
                                [AdmissionDate] => 42569

                            )

               ...
```

Comment: What your are trying to do?

Comment: You mean you get a unix timestamp or something like that in your xml file ? `42569` doesn't make any sense really

Comment: @Vincent Yeah! I agree but when I import it into Excel it formats to 18/07/2016.

Comment: Excel save dates as amount of days after 1 jan 1900 year

Comment: @splash58 Thank you that was it! If I subtract Todays date from 1 Jan 1900 I get 42,567. How can I accept your comment as the answer?

Comment: @snowflakes74 i've written the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel save dates as amount of days after 1 jan 1900 year

```
$days = 42569;
$d = new DateTime('1900-01-01');
echo $d->modify("+$days day")->format('r'); // Wed, 20 Jul 2016 00:00:00 +0000
```