# how to format a longinteger to date

Tags: php

I have a value which represents a date format from an excelfile. I import the excel file which contains bankdata so I need the correct date values.

For example 43676 which is the same like 2019-07-30.

Now I want to format it to date, that it really shows 2019-07-30.

Here my testsnippet:

```
$value = 43676;
$datum = date("Y-m-d",  $value);
echo $datum;
```

The result is 1970-01-01? So how can I get the right value for this number?

I tried different formats and functions, but nothing ended in success. Any help appreciated.

Comment: May be it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38430202/how-to-translate-date-in-int-format-in-xml/38430705#38430705

Comment: Add the time to the output. `$datum = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",  $value);` that number is equal to `1970-01-01 12:07:56`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the ugliest answer but it will work...

```
$value = 43676;

$date = new DateTime('1899-12-30');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P'. $value .'D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

Comment: but it works ;-)